# SMARTY doesn't display 0

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I have an issue with SMARTY after update to the latest version.
When I use IF/ELSE statement, and it should display 0, it doesn't display anything:

template.tpl:

```
var xxxF = {{if false}}1{{else}}0{{/if}};
var xxxT = {{if true}}1{{else}}0{{/if}};
```

result: (rendered source):

```
var xxxF = ;
var xxxT = 1;
```

Imo, it should be:

```
var xxxF = 0;
var xxxT = 1;
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Smarty usually uses single braces. Does the same happen when you use `{if false}1{else}0{/if}`?

Comment: yes, but in my code I have to use doubled braces `($smarty->setLeftDelimiter('{{');)`

Comment: May I ask why? I could imagine that whatever forces you to do that is responsible for the problem, not smarty.

Comment: the system was built in that way, in case of JavaScript's issues with braces.

Comment: why should smarty interfere with javascript? anyway ... I can't reproduce your problem with the current version of Smarty (3.1.29), I get the output `var xxxF = 0;`

Comment: Oh, somebody re-invented the wheel. It is a square wheel, of course, as `Smarty` provides by design not one but two ways to avoid problems with the usage of curly braces in Javascript and CSS: [`{ldelim}, {rdelim}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.ldelim.tpl) and [`{literal}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.literal.tpl).

Comment: Identify the compiled file generated by Smarty in `templates_c` and take a look at it. It's convoluted but it's PHP; you can find out what Smarty understood from your template and why its output looks like this.

Comment: Well, I'm not the one who can change it. I'm working on the system which just has been built in that way, and I don't think, changing it a way back to the single braces will be the brightest idea. But anyway, shouldn't it work fine no matter of what kind of the delimiters are used?

Comment: It does. I tried it with both single and double braces. Works in both cases.

Comment: Here is how SMARTY "see it": `var xxxF = <?php if (false) {?>1<?php } else {
}?>;`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly was the source of the issue, but on the compiled file generated by Smarty in `templates_c` I noticed the version of Smarty was **3.1.28**, not the latest (**3.1.29**).

After I updated it to the latest version, the issue is gone and now it works fine.

Thank you for your comments, all of them leaded me to the place where I was able to fix it.